# Multiple domains for site subsections

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

Here's the deal. Basically I've got multiple domains, and I would like one of the domains to point to the regular base of the site, but the other domains to point to a subsection of the site **without** modifying the url in the address bar. The idea is that each of the extra domains are branded for their section.

Example:
www.domain.com Top level of site
www.domain2.com points to www.domain.com/abc
www.domain3.com points to www.domain.com/def
etc.

Also note that in the example 'abc' and 'def' are not real directories on the filesystem, but are virtual areas defined in a database.

I've spent quite a bit of time looking around and couldn't find anything that fits this. I do **not** want to use domain cloaking because it uses frames. Regular redirects obviously are easy to point to the right thing, but they change the url in the address bar.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

**Edit:**
I've added the alias as Mark suggested below, but can anyone shed light on how I could then use mod_rewrite to make this work?

Comment: Do you have access to the DNS servers?

Comment: I can edit the dns records, yes.

Comment: Sorry for the massive delay in responding to your request for additional help. Unfortunately, without knowing the details of your situation, it is hard to give you a complete solution, but I did edit my answer to give you a hint. If you feel comfortable sharing more details, contact me at markeirich.com/contact. Otherwise, you'll need to study some mod_rewrite examples online, or hire someone.

Answer (score 5):

First, your DNS records need to point to the IP of the web server.

Second, you have to set up Apache to serve multiple domains from the same VirtualHost. Enable mod_alias and then use the ServerAlias directive in your VirtualHost definition. For example:

```
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com www.domain2.com domain2.com www.domain3.com domain3.com
```

If you've done that correctly, you should see the exact same content at each domain, without any redirection.

What you do next is an architectural decision. You can use mod_rewrite to hard-code URL routing rules based on domain, or you can use PHP to do the routing, based on the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].

A mod_rewrite solution might involve adding something like this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /abc/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain3\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /def/$1 [L]
```

This is a high-level overview. Please comment on my answer if you need details on a particular part of the process.

Comment: First off - thanks for the answer. Good to know this should be possible. A little elaboration would be nice. I understand what you're talking about but I need some specifics. If you can provide a sample <VirtualHost> directive that would help. Using mod_rewrite or php from there is fine, but what exactly I'd need to be doing I'm not sure - partly because I'm not sure how that ties in with the Alias.

Comment: Thanks for the alias bit. That's what I pretty much expected. What I'm most unclear about is how mod_rewrite could be used to then map all requests for domain2.com to domain1.com/abc and domain3.com to domain1.com/def without it changing the url in the address bar. It's possible that I could incorporate such a thing into my php code, but I'd rather not as the routing is already a completed enough situation and separating this out would make things a lot easier.