# Rewrite URL to file in sub-folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to direct my pretty URL's to use files within a sub-folder. For example, I'd like to do:

```
RewriteRule ^someurl$ ./views/file.php [NC]
```

So then the URL would be http://example.com/someurl. In practice, my example produces a 500 internal error.

Comment: Rule is good. Are you getting any problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess RewriteRule to path without changing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803615/htaccess-rewriterule-to-path-without-changing-url)

Comment: Asking if something is possible does not make a good question.

Comment: duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732095/multiple-domains-for-site-subsections

Comment: Check your Apache error.log and report error here